# How to setup multiple routing entries for socket?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, routes

I am very new to static routing, our client requested to implement static routing for sockets. When I googled I came across with `rtentry` to set routing information. When I opened this structure I saw the fields for static routing

```
struct sockaddr rt_dst;     /* Target address.  */
struct sockaddr rt_gateway;     /* Gateway addr (RTF_GATEWAY).  */
struct sockaddr rt_genmask;     /* Target network mask (IP).  */
```

But how can I setup multiple entry here?
creating multiple `rtentry` and calling `ioctl(FileDes, SIOCADDRT, &rtentry)` will fix my problem?

```
int32_t FileDes = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);
for(auto RtEntry : RtEntriesList)
{
   ioctl(FileDes, SIOCADDRT, RtEntry)`
}
```

If I configure, how can I test this? It will be helpful if you can provide a link to know more about these things.

Comment: Gilson, can you expand the "client requested to implement static routing for sockets" part of your question into more detail? Sockets usually have no any additional routing selection, they just uses system-wide defined routing; and rtentry is not for normal sockets, it is for administrative sockets to get and set system-wide routing (it is used by privileged `route add` command: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/274094/can-not-add-static-route-in-my-ubuntu-siocaddrt-network-is-unreachable).

Comment: @osgx we have to modify /etc/network/interface file to provide static routing. I am clear about that part also we have to set these routing information to interface so that it will take the configuration without restarting. For that we have to set the routing information through administrative sockets. So I am confused how to set these informations.  They dont want to execute the route command or restart the device to set static routing configuration. I hope you are clear about my question.

Comment: Gilson, check sources of `route` or [`ip route`](https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_ip_command_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print.pdf) tools (sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools, ) and/or do `strace`/`ltrace`/`sysdig` of `route add` commands which are used to set desired routing.

Comment: Thanks @osgx its working. rtentry is added to routing table and using wireshark I checked, all the messages are routing to given gateway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got my answers.

```
int32_t FileDes = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);

struct rtentry Route1;
struct rtentry Route2;
struct rtentry Route3;

// configure Route1
// configure Route2
// configure Route3

RtEntriesList.push_back(&Route1);
RtEntriesList.push_back(&Route2);
RtEntriesList.push_back(&Route3);

for(auto RtEntry : RtEntriesList)
{
   ioctl(FileDes, SIOCADDRT, RtEntry);
}
```

will work, we can create multple routing entries and add to the socket FD. and this will update the system wide routing table.

its similar to `route add ..` command

for testing i set the gateway as my PC ip address and started wireshark there. after setting routing configurations the given range of IP is routed to my PC. Thanks @osgx for the information that its actually setting the system wide routing table.